# PHP ASP like tags and way of outputting variables

Tags: php, variables, tags

I was wondering if there's any way of inserting a PHP variable in HTML without having to use `echo`. In ASP, you can use `<%=variable%>` but in PHP uou have always to use `echo`. 
In phpBB source code I see that `{VARIABLE}` is used to do this but I don't know how do they achieve it. I am sure it's not related to PHP configuration. Do you know some references or information related to this? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have shorttags enabled* you can use the following syntax to output something:

```
<?=$variableName?> 
<?="Hello world"?>
```

* The [manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.short-open-tag) states short_open_tags is only required before php 5.4, this syntax will always work 5.4+.

Comment: Thanks, I thought that I should enable it in php configuration but I have 5.4+

Comment: @ali Keep in mind that short tags are [not really recommanded](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/200640/are-php-short-tags-acceptable-to-use). You can also use the ASP tags <%=variable%> by enabling `asp_tags` in `php.ini`

Answer (score 1):

`<?= $var ?>` equals `<?php echo $var; ?>`